# Jquery select option copy makes different output

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to copy `dropdown` from `one` to `another`, But when it `appends` it will remove the `options` from the `previous one`. Why?

My code is :

**HTML:**

```
<select id="dropdown" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
</select>
<select id="options2"></select>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').on('change',function(){
        $("#dropdown option:selected").each(function(){
            $("#options2").append($(this));            
        });
    });    
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/5BU4T/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the clone of the element and then append.

```
$("#options2").append($(this).clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#options2").append("<option value='"+$(this).html()+"'>"+$(this).html()+"</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.clone()` and also remember to ignore duplicates.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').on('change',function(){
        $("#dropdown option:selected").each(function(){
            var vThis = $(this);
            // check if already added in the dropdown, dont append again
            var toAppend = true;
            $('#options2 option').each(function(){
                    if($(this).val() == vThis.val())
                    {
                        toAppend = false;
                        return;
                    }
            });

            if(toAppend == true)
                $("#options2").append(vThis.clone());     
        });
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').on('change',function(){
        $("#dropdown option:selected").each(function(){
            if(!$("#options2 option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").length)
            //to remove redundancy
               $("#options2").append($(this).clone());            
        });
    });    
});
```